# ¿Como puedo cambiar el formato de una fecha en Lenguaje SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

Estoy trabajando con la base de datos HR de SQL (ORACLE), y quisiera saber como cambiar el formato de fecha

#### Formato actual

- 17/06/03

#### Formato futuro o esperado

- 17 de junio del año 2003

Comment: Disculpa, cuando hablas de `sql developer`, a que haces referencia, podrías colocar el motor o la herramienta con la cual estés trabajando?, `mysql`, `postgresql`, `oracle`, etc.

Comment: Mira [ask] <-ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha    y haz el [tour] <-ACA para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Con que tipo de datos estan guardados esas fechas? porque puede ser solo un problema de visualizacion. Y siempre aclara que base de datos es.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es recuperar los resultados guardados en BDD con ese formato, en las selects que uses para obtener las fechas puedes usar este formateo. Seguramente exista alguna forma mas eficiente, pero bueno, lo dejo por aquí:

```
select to_char(col_fecha, 'DD') || ' de ' ||to_char(col_fecha, 'MONTH') || ' del año ' || to_char(col_fecha, 'YYYY') 
from tabla;
```

Si el campo es nullable necesitaras meter un `CASE WHEN` para controlar esos casos específicos.

Answer (score 0):

No es necesario complejos cases, `TO_CHAR` puede manejar el formato. Solo necesitas pasarle el código de valor `NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE` adecuado. La solución aceptada puede que no de el resultado correcto (para el valor del mes) si el `NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE` de la sesión es otro distinto a `SPANISH`

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(CAMPO_FECHA, 'DD "de" Month "del año" YYYY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=SPANISH') FROM tabla;
```

Salida:

```
08 de Marzo del año 2018
```